# Delete using join or using sub-query?

Tags: performance, mysql-5.5, join, subquery, query-performance

I need to delete rows from a table based on what is present in a temporary table.

For me, both of these statements work :

```
DELETE from main_table where `id` in (select `deletable_id` from temporary_table);
```

and

```
DELETE main_table from main_table join temporary_table on main_table.id = temporary_table.deletable_id;
```

Which of the two is advisable to use given the fact that main_table will be having a billion of rows and the temporary will have a few thousands.

Comment: You should have a test system. Can't you perform tests? Profile both queries - **with** realistic datasets - the optimiser can change the plan depending on data volumes.

Comment: The version of MySql here used (5.5) does not support explain on delete statements. And yes, I can do tests. Thought I will get some answers here before running the tests.

Comment: I scratched the EXPLAIN - you should be able to [PROFILE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274892/measuring-actual-mysql-query-time). Both queries should work - it's very difficult to give further information without CPU/RAM + disk, network and app configurations. There does come a point where you have to test on your own system :-(

Comment: Test, as @Vérace suggests. The result will very probably be in favour of join but it never hurts to test.

Answer (score 0):

In the given scenario where the main_table has billions of rows and the temporary_table has only a few thousand rows, the *second statement would generally be more efficient*

```
DELETE main_table FROM main_table JOIN temporary_table ON main_table.id = temporary_table.deletable_id;
```

Rationale :

an `inner join` between the `main_table and temporary_table based on the id column,` allows for a `direct match` and elimination of rows to be deleted.

On the other hand, the first statement uses a `subquery with the IN clause`, which needs to be executed for each row in the `main_table`, resulting in potentially slower performance.

P.S.

That is assuming there is `Indexing` on the `Join column` and `stats` updated periodically. If  there's no indexing and stats there then still it will be good . Only with stale stats will the sub-query show up as closely competitive but for so many  rows  in the main table I doubt if it will still come close to the IJ